# Check the reason the computer resumed from hibernation

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

I am creating an application that puts the computer in hibernation for a few hours or even a full week (Using a WaitableTimer and WaitForSingleObject).

There are three reasons why the computer could wake-up

1. The waitable timer expired and the computer resumes as scheduled.
2. The user presses the power button which resumes the computer.
3. The computer turns on unexpectedly.

The first two reasons are perfectly acceptable, they are what the system is designed for. The third reason is of course not so nice.

I would like to be able to differentiate between these three reasons for turning on. Is there any way to do this?  It seems here that in the first scenario the `WaitForSingleObject` method should return `WAIT_OBJECT_0` [(source)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx). If this is not the case it is either scenario 2 or 3 but I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two. Is there an API to check the reason for resuming from standby?

Another (better) option is to prohibit other devices/software to wake up the computer (e.g. eliminating scenario 3). I have disallowed wake-up capabilities of all devices I see when I run `powercfg -devicequery -wake_armed` (when I run the command now the it returns NONE). Is there a similar way to see all (active) software that has scheduled the computer to wake up?

*(If its any help the computer this software is designed for is a surface 3 pro, with the included (and updated) Windows 8.1 OS installed)*

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same as pressing the power button, but pressing keys on the keyboard also wake's-up the computer (maybe also mouse clicks but I'm not 100% sure about that).

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking about waking from Hibernate (S4) states? So, not from ACPI Sleep (S3) or Connected Standby states. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. I can't see anything the ACPI specification ( http://acpi.info/DOWNLOADS/ACPI_5_Errata%20A.pdf ) that provides details about specific messages provided to the OS after a hibernate event such as the cause of the resurrection.

Comment: If you don't own/control all software on the computer, which it sounds like you don't, then wouldn't "is to prohibit other devices/software to wake up the computer" run afoul of Raymond Chen's ["What if two programs did this?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx) thought experiment?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have 100% control over the computer after I'm doing configuring it is locked away in a box and the only active component is a touch screen and the power button.

Comment: @RogerRowland yes S4 Hibernation.  (Usually unavailable on a surface but I've disabled connected standby to make the option available again)

Comment: @Deruijter there is no keyboard, the only way of input is the touch screen. Which cannot wake the system up (I've tried :) ).

Comment: When the computer "turns on unexpectedly", does the event log show any reason? Have you disabled any scheduled tasks? [This MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggests that *"When the system wakes automatically, it broadcasts the PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC event to all applications"* - is that useful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1/ You can query the Windows Event Log to see what caused the computer to wake up:

```
  var log = new EventLog("System");
  var wakeUpEntry = (from entry in log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
    where entry.Source == "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter"
          && entry.InstanceId == 1
    orderby entry.TimeWritten descending
    select entry).First();

  Console.WriteLine("{0}", wakeUpEntry.Message);
```

The message has a "Wake Source" entry ("4USB Root Hub" for instance) that you can parse if you really want to do it programmatically.

2/ You can check if any Windows or external program has set a wake timer on the system with this command:

```
powercfg -waketimers
```

If neither command (yours nor this one) shows anything, most of the possible causes have been eliminated.

3/ You can even disable wake timers completely on this machine. In Windows *Power Options*, *Plan Settings*, *Advanced Plan Settings*, Disable *Allow wake timers* under the *Sleep* section. I'm not sure if Windows Scheduled Maintenance is affected by this, but you can also turn it off, of course.

4/ Another safety: make sure no devices in the BIOS settings are allowed to wake the PC up, whenever it's configurable.

Comment: This is a great answer. The event log gives me exactly the information I need, and `powercfg -waketimers` pointed me to another culprit (windows scheduled the computer to wake up for maintenance, however it seems non-trivial to delete this waketimer :) ). +151 ;)

Comment: Humbug, Wake Source is always "Unknown" no matter if I turned it on manually or if it was a waketimer... extremely annoying that Windows doesn't fill this field.

Comment: Strange, on my machine this field is almost always set: "Device -Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Detection Driver (USB)", "Power Button", "Device -USB Root Hub", "Timer - Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\TaskScheduler\Regular Maintenance' scheduled task that requested waking the computer"... I do have some "Unknown" entries, I don't know what they are related to.

Comment: To get rid of Windows Maintenance timers, just go to *Action Center* / *Maintenance* / *Change Maintenance Settings* and uncheck *Allow Maintenance to wake up my computer*.

Comment: After some Googling it seems that they are properly set when a device wakes the computer up, but otherwise.. no clue :).

Answer (score 1):

After following the instructions in [this article](http://lifehacker.com/how-find-out-what-woke-up-your-computer-last-1550549116) (particularly seeing what last woke it up with `powercfg -lastwake`) I found a mention (in [this linked article](http://www.howtogeek.com/122954/how-to-prevent-your-computer-from-waking-up-accidentally/)) that:

> **Windows 10 has a new “feature” that wakes the computer up** for what
>   they call **“important wake timers”**, and you will want to disable that
>   if your computer is waking up all the time. Head into Power Options
>   just like we show above, and then find Sleep -> Allow wake timers ->
>   Plugged in and change the setting from Important Wake Timers Only to
>   Disable.

*(emphasis mine)*

Pretty sure that's the culprit that wakes my computer from hibernation, but haven't confirmed.

Comment: Wake Timers are not a new feature of Windows 10 (no idea what ThinkGeek based that claim on). They have been around for a while :).  Unfortunately I need the wake timers myself to wake up the computer when  I want it. In the end it turned out that the Scheduled Maintenance tasks regularly re-enables itself, even after it has been disabled manually. This caused my computer to turn on unwanted.

Comment: I think they meant the 'important wake timers' prioritization (option) is new; how did you find out that the Scheduled Maintenance task was re-enabling itself and how did you "fix" that?