# How to print computer wake source?

Tags: c#, windows, event-log

I would like to print wake source from event viewer (Windows 10).

Is there a way I can access the event viewer->system log , search for:

`Source: Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter` latest event, parse the event Message and print the wake source?

Here is an example of event log:

```
Index              : 2841
EntryType          : Information
InstanceId         : 1
Message            : The system has resumed from sleep.

                     Sleep Time: 2010-10-01T19:19:37.239789600Z
                     Wake Time: 2010-10-01T21:28:48.921200800Z

                     Wake Source: 4HID Keyboard Device
Category           : (0)
CategoryNumber     : 0
Source             : Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter
```

Comment: @Christian.K I think the duplicate is incorrect, since the question pointed to , suggest how to analyze the wake source where my question focus on parsing the event viewer for system log and finding the wake source. though the answer is the same - people may find it much quicker using my question.

Comment: However I think the question _itself_ is the same (albeit your answer/solution) is more detailed. Maybe it would be a proper solution to edit the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28148903/21567) augmenting it with your code for actually parsing the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone concern about a solution - I've succeeded doing the following:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Get Last Wake Event Entry
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="wakeMessage"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static EventLogEntry GetLastWakeEventEntry(out string[] wakeMessage)
        {
            wakeMessage = null;
            EventLogEntry wakeEntry = null;
            //Open system event log of current user
            var eventLog = new EventLog("System", ".");
            //Get all event log entries
            var entries = eventLog.Entries;
            //Start from the latest event message until finding the wake event log
            for (int i = entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (entries[i].Source == "Microsoft-Windows-Power-Troubleshooter" && entries[i].InstanceId == 1)
                {
                    wakeEntry = entries[i];
                    wakeMessage = Regex.Split(entries[i].Message, @"([\r\n])");
                    break;
                }
            }
            return wakeEntry;
        }
```

Given the last wake entry and wake message, one can parse the message for wake source (usually the last message line) and display related info given the wake entry.

Hope it helps.